# URL for H2 DB console on Play! 2.0

Tags: playframework-2.0

This must be very simple, but I couldn't find it on the documentation.

In Play! 1.2 I was able to log into the DB console using the following URL:

http://localhost:9000/@db

It doesn't seem to work anymore on Play! 2.0 (I get an 'action not found' message). Do you know what's the URL for the DB console in Play! 2.0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First run the 'h2-browser' command on the Play console. After that it is accesible on http://localhost:8082/

Comment: I got this to work, however the test database isn't appearing in the viewer. any idea why?

Comment: The database is created on the first request. Are you sure you've done at least one request to your application?